# How can I write a C program to execute for a certain number of processor seconds?

Tags: c, busy-waiting, cpu-time

I need a C program that would execute for a precise number of CPU seconds passed in as a parameter.  I need such a program in order to test code that monitors a process' CPU usage.

Example:

```
busywait x
```

Should run for x seconds on my processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the C program I wrote to solve my problem.  It continuously checks the number of clock cycles until the correct number of processor-seconds has been used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
     clock_t start, end;
     double cpu_time_used;
     int wait;

     sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &wait);

     start = clock();
     end = clock();
     while (((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < wait)
     {
          end = clock();
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just type in `sleep x` in a shell where x is seconds. I only tested on bash on a Mac, but I believe other unixes should have the same thing.

Comment: So far as I can tell, the sleep command does not busy wait.  I can't seem to find a definitive link to support my claim however.

Comment: Sleep ? By definition it's not a busy wait (well, sleeping might be "busy" in old ms-dos stuff by the way). I think the easier way to waste CPU cycle accomplishing nothing of value is to build your own "dirtysleep" program, go and consume CPU time :)

Comment: Yeah I looked around a bit and it isn't. Sorry!

Comment: @Pascail but what's the main difference between sleep and busy wait, I mean when we use busy wait and not sleep